# Does salt increase security if there is only a single hashed password?

Tags: hash, salt

Say there is only a single hashed password in the passwords file.

If it was salted, would that make it more secure?

My logic is:

Yes because SALT helps protect against rainbow tables and dictionary attacks. Which would make it more secure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely.  If no salt is used, then a precalculated set of tables, called rainbow table, can be used to determine the plaintext of the password.  With salt, a brute force process of calculating every possible value till the hash is matched is the only way to find the password.

Comment: Technically in what way does it protect against an attack with a rainbow table? It does only make the password longer, but that is not really a protection against a precalculated rainbow table, just a requirement for a rainbow table calculated for longer strings. I don't understand this statement.

Comment: @techraf - because nobody calculates rainbow tables for anything the size of a typical salt.  Random 8-character alpha-numeric passwords would take 24 terabytes (without the resulting hash!), and salts are usually longer still.  You could calculate a table for a single salt, but it would only be useful _once_, essentially, and since you'd get the salt at the same time as the password, building the rainbow table would be equivalent to cracking the hash.